# Kaltura KMC:: Flash Error

Tags: flash, kaltura

I installed Kaltura using the instructions found [here](https://github.com/kaltura/platform-install-packages/blob/master/doc/install-kaltura-redhat-based.md). The installation went on without any error. However, when i tried to access KMC, it says Flash is not installed even though Flash is installed in the system.

I have looked up this issue elsewhere and tried the solution given there (i.e. changing request_order values to GPC in the php.ini). However it did not work.

I also tried the solution mentioned [here](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/585794-kaltura-troubles), but I could not get it working as.

At last, I tried to access the KMC SWF directly. By accessing the swf file directly, though it displays the login page however, when I try to login, it gives a Flash Error #2048. I tried to include the crossd

Any Help to resolve this will be appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was resolved after updating Flash Pluging using the following steps:

rpm -ivh http://linuxdownload.adobe.com/adobe-release/adobe-release-x86_64-1.0-1.noarch.rpm

rpm –import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-adobe-linux

yum check-update

yum -y install flash-plugin nspluginwrapper alsa-plugins-pulseaudio libcurl

Thereafter the following changes were required in the Kaltura Database as mentioned [here](https://github.com/kaltura/platform-install-packages/issues/251)

…