# Error while logging in kmc

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, kaltura

I am new to kaltura and I installed it in my aws instance through aws AMI. Now I am trying to login to kmc but it is saying Error #2048. I tried to dig this error and found out that it is not able to get crossdomain.xml. Can someone please help me to fix this 404 for crossdomain.xml

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27141748/kaltura-kmc-flash-error

Comment: I tried the same but still I am getting 404 for crossdomain.xml.

Comment: Can your give the whole error? or it only say Error #2048

Comment: Whenever I am trying to login, it is saying Error #2048. That is it.